# sql, php - запись постов каждого пользователя и их вывод

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица с id, паролем и именем пользователя. Пользователя может добавлять какую-то запись на страницу, но вопрос состоит в том, как её сохранять в базе данных.

Я пробовала вот так:

```
INSERT INTO blog(posts) VALUES ($_POST['posting']) WHERE name = '$name'
```

Но потом узнала, что с INSERT-ом нельзя использовать WHERE.

Подумала, стоит сделать отдельную таблицу для постов, но не уверена как при сабмите пост должен добавиться к юзеру с определенной айдишкой

Пожалуйста, подскажите решение этой задачи.

Comment: правильно подумали, делайте отдельную. с примерно следующим набором полей `id,  user_id, pub_date, title, content`, где `id  `автоинкремент, первичный ключ; `user_id` внешний ключ, `pub_date` по умолчанию `now()`, `content` не `null`

Comment: @teran Ну что за мода ответы в комментариях писать? )) Ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @teran, какие ключи написать - это не особая проблема. Но я никак не могу разобраться как написать запрос добавления в таблицу, понимаете?

Comment: @AK это скорее подсказка, чем ответ

Comment: @Біпач понимаю, Что бы написать запрос, надо понять где какие ключи, и какие они должны иметь значения и как формироваться. после этого надо заполнить все поля.

Comment: @teran но ведь надо знать куда вставлять пост, верно? Разве здесь без какого-то условия WHERE не обойтись?

Comment: insert добавляет новую запись в БД. все колонки которые вы вставляете, все и окажутся в таблице. Если предположить что структура постов как в начале сказал teran, то вставляете `insert into posts(user_id, content, ...) values($USERID, $TEXT, ...)` разумеется ID пользователя получаете заранее, например из сессии того, кто добавляет пост. После этого у вас в таблице лежат все посты отдельными строками и в каждой строке есть ID добавившего пользователя. при выводе можно делать join с таблицей пользователей и обать от туда имена.

Comment: Предположим, что insert позволял бы задавать where. Как известно, where помогает отфильтровать по заданным условиям существующие в таблице записи. Но insert добавляет абсолютно новую запись, которая никакого отношения к уже имеющимся в таблице не имеет, тогда что бы по вашему должен был бы фильтровать where ?

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за помощь) Уже разобралась